# what is the use of 'app.resource' in node js express

Tags: node.js, express

for example :

var Resource = **app.resource** = restful.model('resource', mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    year: Number,
  }))
  .methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app.resource() method returns a new Resource object, which can be used to further map pathnames, nest resources, and more.

The details of the same can be found here: [Express-resource](https://github.com/expressjs/express-resource)